# AWS Pinpoint concurrent messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

Amazon pinpoint two-way SMS service provides a long code to the user which accepts a message and can be hooked to reply separate message. how many concurrent messages can this service handle.

Answer (score 1):

The following is quoted from the  [channels sms awssupport long code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/channels-sms-awssupport-long-code.html)  documentation.

```
In the United States and Canada, sending rates for long codes are restricted to 1 message per second. This limit might be higher or lower in other countries and regions. If you send a large volume of messages from a long code, wireless carriers might begin to block your messages. If you send SMS messages programmatically, your applications should limit the number of messages that they send per second.
```

I hope this helps.